# Como exibir uma ImageView apenas enquanto o usuário está "segurando" a tela?

Tags: android, android-adapter

Estou fazendo um aplicativo e num dos fragmentos tenho uma RecyclerView sendo usada para listar alguns view holders com algumas textviews e uma image view.

Implementei um adapter simples para exibir uma Toast ao clicar no ViewHolder com sucesso, mas agora queria alterar o código para exibir a imagem temporariamente em tela cheia enquanto o usuário mantiver a viewholder pressionada.

As imagens usadas estão todas dentro da pasta drawble, abaixo trechos do código:

```
Adapter:
public class MyFirstAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
private ArrayList<Republica> reps;
private MyOnItemClickListener myOnItemClickListener;

public void setMyOnItemClickListener(MyOnItemClickListener myOnItemClickListener){
    this.myOnItemClickListener = myOnItemClickListener;
}

public interface MyOnItemClickListener {
    void myOnItemClick(String nome);
}


public MyFirstAdapter(ArrayList<Republica> reps) {
    this.reps = reps;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    //return null;
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_republicas, viewGroup, false);
    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (myOnItemClickListener != null) {
                TextView txt = view.findViewById(R.id.txtRepNome);
                myOnItemClickListener.myOnItemClick(txt.getText().toString());
            }
        }
    });

    return new MyFirstViewHolder(v);


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    ((MyFirstViewHolder)viewHolder).bind(reps.get(i));


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.reps.size();
}

public class MyFirstViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView txtNome;
    private TextView txtBio;
    private RatingBar level;
    private Button btnVagas;


    public MyFirstViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        txtNome = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtRepNome);
        txtBio = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtRepBio);
        level = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratebarLevel);
        btnVagas = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonVagas);


    }

    public void bind(final Republica rep){
        imageView.setImageResource(rep.getFoto());
        txtNome.setText(rep.getNome());
        txtBio.setText(rep.getBio());
        level.setRating(rep.getLevel_agitação());

        int vagas = rep.getVagas_permanetes();
        if (vagas == 0){
            btnVagas.setText("Sem vagas");
            btnVagas.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else {
            btnVagas.setText(vagas + " vagas");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Fragmento que usa o adapter:

```
public class RepublicasFragment extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private MyFirstAdapter mAdapter;
private ImageView imgView;


public RepublicasFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_republicas, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.rViewRepublicas);
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mAdapter = new MyFirstAdapter(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Republica.republicas)));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    /*
    Adicionando o Listener
     */
    mAdapter.setMyOnItemClickListener(new MyFirstAdapter.MyOnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void myOnItemClick(String nome) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),nome,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    return v;
}

}
```

Comment: Boa ! De uma olhada no onTouchEvent. E use as propriedades ACTION_DOWN e UP para tratar suas necessidades.